# How can I programmatically add users?

Tags: 9, organic-groups

How can I programmatically add users to an organic group?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since the question is about code, we expect to see the code you wrote so far. If you are asking a question about code before attempting to write code, you are asking the question too early.

Comment: i have tried this but not working ..$membership = Og::createMembership($gid, $account);$membership->save();

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work; replace `$userId` & `$groupId` with approriate values

```php
// Get a User entity via ID
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userId);

// Get a Group entity via ID
$group = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::load($groupId);

// Add member and save
$group->addMember($user);
$group->save();
```

You can use the following to get the currently logged in userID

```php
$userId = \Drupal::currentUser()->id()
```

Comment: Getting error like "Error: Class 'Drupal\group\Entity\Group' not found "i think this above solution for Group module but want to add in Organic Group module (og_group) not in the Group module.